# Create a CLI interface with Node own commands not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

Currently I am following the following [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-interactive-command-line-application-with-nodejs)

The tutorial basically is meant to create a node cli that allow me to CRUD contacts directly on the cli.

I want to do it without mongoose, since what I need is to perform cli commands that does requests to the server to extract data, but that is other history, just to explain that I do not use mongoose here. The first step worked well, basically if I do: node contact.js -- help, it calls the help command on my contact.js file.

The issue comes when I want to take out the node command, I basically want to call it like that, contact --help. That is not working, I used yarn link and followed the instructions on the tutorial, so what is wrong? Any help?

**Here is what I did so far:**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "contacto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "bin": "./contact.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.15.1",
    "inquirer": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.12"
  }
}
```

**contact.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * We build a cli that is responsable to interact with the IPMA service, to filter any option, for options we mean: Temperature
 * eartquake activity and another possible options, the next argument will be the zone(city), 
 */

const program = require('commander');

program
.version('0.0.1')
.description('Contact management system');

program
.command('addContact <firstame> <lastname> <phone> <email>')
.alias('a')
.description('Add a contact')
.action((firstname, lastname, phone, email) => {
  console.log(firstname,lastname,phone,email);
});

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

The executable is created based on the package name, not on the name of the folder or the file.

As you have defined in the **package.json**, the name of the module is **contacto** (mind the 'o' at the end). This is the global executable name after you run the command `yarn link`.

The right way to execute the CLI in this case is: `contacto --help`

Comment: i get this: contacto : The term 'contacto' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I assume you are working on Windows. In that case there is a known issue when creating symlinks (https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3343). Try running the command as administrator or activating them for everybody from the settings for developers

Comment: oh, thought the issue with window was just about the console -.-, will try it and will say something soon